# Hardcoded and optional [if] statements in program using syntax

Tags: if-statement, syntax, stata

I'm learning how to use the optional `syntax` when writing simple Stata programs and I'm wondering if it's possible to hardcode `if` statements while at the same time passing optional `[if]` statements through the `syntax` options.

I know that a simple function can be written like:

```
sysuse auto

program meanprice
    syntax [if]

    mean price `if'
end
```

and then I can for example use some optional `if` statements like:

```
meanprice if price > 6000 & rep78 > 2
```

However, let's say I want to hardcode the `price > 6000` statement and still be able to selectively choose optional `if` statements. The reason I want to do this is that the part I want to hardcode is very rigorous and I always want to pass these options through some nested programs that I'm writing without having to specify them each time.

I have tried using e.g.,

```
program meanprice_test
    syntax [if]

    mean price if price > 6000 `if'
end
```

but this does clearly not work (to my understanding because `syntax` is parsing text/strings?)

Is there any simple way to achieve the desired outcome using `syntax` and `[if]`? I can think of some very tedious workarounds that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Although I addressed this as a programming question, the more I think about it the more it seems a bad programming strategy. See GENERAL COMMENTS below for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are defining in Stata terms is a command, not a function.

"clearly does not work" should always be explained by giving the error message, or other explicit result that indicates a problem.

That aside, consider this:

```
program meanprice_test
    syntax [if/]

    if "`if'" != "" local if "& (`if')" 
    mean price if price > 6000 `if'
end 


. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. meanprice_test if foreign

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =          9

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
       price |   8783.667   827.6595       6875.08    10692.25
--------------------------------------------------------------

. meanprice_test

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =         23

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
       price |   9655.696    635.944      8336.829    10974.56
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem with your code is not that `syntax` is parsing text [that's its job, always] but that the combination of two `if`s requires more care. What you had would produce stuff like ... `if` ... `if` ... which is illegal.

So, if a user supplies an `if` qualifier (optional for the user, but syntactically not an option)

1. You need to get `syntax` to strip off the user-supplied `if`. How to do this is documented in `help syntax`.
2. Then you need to use `&` to combine the two `if` conditions. Parenthesising may help.

EDIT: If quoted strings are ever to be used in the user's `if`, then use compound double quotes in the program:

```
if `"`if'"' != "" local if `"& (`if')"'
```

GENERAL COMMENTS: While what you want is programmable, I think it's unnecessary and questionable practice:

1. For an audit trail of analysis, a do-file with a `keep if` statement near the beginning and a corresponding log file should suffice as a reproducible record of work on a subset of data.
2. For an audit trail, conversely, the use of highly specialised programs with data-specific constraints built into the code is easy to misunderstand or overlook, especially for others using your work, or even yourself at a later date.
3. Following this strategy carries the burden of writing lots of very specific programs, a poor use of time and energy, and of little use to others.